# android update view at runtime

Tags: android, layout, refresh

I have a custom imageView and I change it's background drawable at runtime. Images don't have the same height and when a resource have higher height, the top margin does not update itself (if top margin is 2 dp and after I set another resource as background which is higher with 2 do, the top margin becomes 0 because layout hasn't updated). How to force layout to update itself at runtime and not schedule a layout pass in the future? I've tried with:

```
imageView.invalidate()
imageView.requestLayout()
imageView.forceLayout()
parent.updateViewLayout(imageView, layoutParams)
```

but none of these methods works. The layout is updated only after I switch device's orientation. Do you have any ideas how to force layout to be refreshed at runtime?